# Adding Previous and Next buttons to Audio Player

Tags: swift, xcode, button

I'm curious how to add functionality to the next/previous buttons. I have more .mp3 files in my project, but I'm not sure how to set the button functions to click through them. I think I need to set a variable and call the viewdidload() function inside the button function. I am just not 100% certain how to do that.
Noob here, be nice. :)

```
var player =  AVAudioPlayer()
var timer = Timer()


@objc func updateScrubber(){

       scrubber.value = Float(player.currentTime)

   }

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

    player.play()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateScrubber), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func pause(_ sender: Any) {

    player.pause()
}

@IBAction func previous(_ sender: Any) {


}

@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {


}


@IBAction func sliderMoved(_ sender: Any) {

    player.volume = volume.value
}
@IBOutlet weak var volume: UISlider!

@IBAction func scrubberMoved(_ sender: Any) {

     player.currentTime = TimeInterval(scrubber.value)
}
@IBOutlet weak var scrubber: UISlider!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "threatofjoy", ofType: "mp3")

    do {

        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath! ))

        scrubber.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)

    } catch {

        print("Error")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by placing the songs in an array and creating a current song function to call in the button methods.